# Insertion sort algorithm behaves differently when put in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, undefined-behavior, insertion-sort

I have the following code to implement insertion sort:

```
int main()
{   
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int a[SIZE] = {8, 6, 10, 2, 16, 4, 18, 14, 12, 10};

    //insertionSort(a, SIZE);

    // The following code is used in the insertionSort() function call above. To use the function, uncomment the function call above, and comment out the code below

    // Start of code used by insertionSort() function
    int temp;
    for (int i=1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; a[j] < a[j-1]; j--)
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = temp;
        }
    }
    // End of code used by insertionSort() function

    return 0;   
}

void insertionSort(int a[], const int SIZE)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i=1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; a[j] < a[j-1]; j--)
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm works fine when the code is used in main(), but it produces wrong results when it's called via insertionSort().

I've determined that the issue is this: the inner loop condition (a[j] < a[j-1]) does not stop the loop when j reaches 0, so it continues to access the array using the negative index. Changing the condition to (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]) works as expected.

I would like to know why this behaviour only exhibits when the loop runs inside insertionSort() but not when it runs in main().

Comment: `for (int j=i; a[j] < a[j-1]; j--)`  What happens on the next iteration if `j == 1` and `a[j] >= a[j-1]`?

Comment: "*so it continues to access the array using the negative index.*" Well, that's undefined behavior then, and there simply is no guarantee on how that'll manifest. This could corrupt the stack, and then the additional function call makes all the difference.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: @Blaze Yes, accessing the array using a negative index will yield undefined behaviour. The issue here is that when the same code runs in main(), the loop stops when j reaches 0, but does not stop when the same code runs in insertionSort(), where j goes into the negative. Why this difference in behaviour between main() and insertionSort()?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The input is always the same: the array "a" as defined in the code

Comment: @Chipster I have not tried a debugger, I've only used debug statements and confirmed that indeed j becomes negative. But this never happens when the code runs in main(). This is the concern.

Answer (score 3):

This loop

```
    for (int j=i; a[j] < a[j-1]; j--)
    {
        temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j-1];
        a[j-1] = temp;
    }
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is no check that `j` shall be greater than `0`.

Otherwise when for example `j` is equal to `0` then there is access beyond the array using the index `-1`

```
a[0] < a[-1]
```

Here is a demonstrative program with the updated loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 8, 6, 10, 2, 16, 4, 18, 14, 12, 10 };
    const size_t SIZE = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i; j != 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]; --j )
        {
            std::swap( a[j-1], a[j] );
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
8 6 10 2 16 4 18 14 12 10 
2 4 6 8 10 10 12 14 16 18
```

And including the algorithm in a function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void insertionSort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i; j != 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]; --j )
        {
            std::swap( a[j-1], a[j] );
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 8, 6, 10, 2, 16, 4, 18, 14, 12, 10 };
    const size_t SIZE = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    insertionSort( a, SIZE );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as shown above

```
8 6 10 2 16 4 18 14 12 10 
2 4 6 8 10 10 12 14 16 18
```

Comment: Having " j != 0 " in your loop condition is what makes this code work. I addressed this in the post (though I used "j < 0" instead of "j != 0"). 

What I would like to know is why the iteration stops when j reaches 0 when it runs in main(), but does not stop when it runs in insertionSort().


Thanks for taking the time, I have learnt some better coding approaches from your code, specifically this: "const size_t SIZE = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )"

Comment: @Niso It depends on what was in the memory before the first element of the array.

Comment: It must be more than that. With the algorithm in main(), I've run the executable in an infinite bash loop and the results remain the same, and it's always correct. It doesn't seem like undefined behavior,  nor does it seem that I'm just lucky.

Comment: @Niso Accessing memory beyond an array is undefined behavior by the definition.

Comment: I see your point, agreed. I would just like to know why it does not exhibit the same behaviour when in main().

Comment: @Niso As I said it depends on what is in the memory before the first element of the array.

Comment: Alright. I'll try running this under different scenarios to see what happens. It's conceivable that right now, what's in memory before the array is causing the loop to terminate and appear to behave correctly, though it's actually incorrect.

Comment: @Niso For example try to run your program with the declarations int main() 
{
 int b[] = { 20 };
 int a[] = { 8, 6, 10, 2, 16, 4, 18, 14, 12, 10 };
 int c[] = { 20 };
    const size_t SIZE = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); and see what resul will be. As for me then I for example got the following result 8 6 10 2 16 4 18 14 12 10 
4 6 2592 8 10 10 12 14 16 18